# White screen for DD4T application intermediate

Tags: 2011, dd4t

We've a DD4T application with MVC and it sometimes in between it starts to show a blank page, don't know the reason for it.Feels like it starts to give Page not found error for all the pages.

The moment we restart the App-Pool for application it starts to work fine.

We are using Tridion 2011 SP1.

Thanks
Tarun Panwar

Answer (score 3):

A White Screen means that the Page Rendition has stopped and you are not receiving a complete page. What you are describing is an internal server error that is hidden by the Error Page. I would suggest checking the Event Viewer and Web Server Logs in order to get more information about the exception.

You said that restarting the Application Pool fix the issue temporarily, it can indicate a Threads Contention or Memory related issue